# Debugging craps game simulation in C

Tags: c

Before scoffing at my erroneous code let me briefly inform you what I am trying to accomplish, and where I am going wrong.

Craps is a game played with 2 dice. If you roll 7 or 11 on the first roll you win. If you roll 2, 3 or 12 on the first roll you lose. Any other roll is called the "point" and the game continues. Now the player wins if on any subsequent roll the player rolls "point" again. However if the player rolls a 7 before rolling the "point" then the player loses. Any other roll (aside from "point" or 7) is ignored and we continue rolling until we hit "point" or 7.

In my simulation the `roll_dice` function should generate two random numbers between 1 and 6 and add them. The `play_game` function should play one craps game and returns `true` if the player wins and `false` if the player loses. It is also responsible for displaying messages showing the results of the player's dice rolls. We keep track of the numbers of wins and losses in `main`.

The problem in my code happens when the `roll_dice` function returns a number that is **not:** 7, 11 or 2, 3, 12. I.e. When it rolls a "point". When it rolls a "point" then the subsequent roll is also always the "point" and the game finishes with a win. I'm looking at the last `for` loop in `play_game` and I suspect the error is there but I don't know why it's wrong. For some reason the value of the `score2` variable is *always* the "point" (if `score1` is a "point") and I don't know why this is the case. Surely by invoking `roll_dice` a second time `score2` should sometimes not be equal to `score1`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int roll_dice(void);
bool play_game(void);

int main(void)
{ 
  int wins = 0, losses = 0;
  
  for(;;) {
    if(play_game())
    { 
      printf("You win!\n");
      wins++;
    } 
    else
    {  
      printf("You lose!\n");
      losses++;
    }
    char x;
    printf("\nPlay again? ");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    getchar();      //absorbs the "ENTER" button once y,Y,n or N has been typed
  
    if(x == 'y' || x == 'Y')
    continue;  
    if(x == 'n' || x == 'N')
    {  
       printf("Wins: %d Losses: %d\n", wins, losses);
       break;
    }
   }

  return 0;
}

int roll_dice(void)
{
  int die1, die2;
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

  die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
  die2 = 1 + rand() % 6;

  return die1 + die2;
}


bool play_game(void)
{
  int score1 = roll_dice();

  if(score1 == 7 || score1 == 11)
  {
    printf("You rolled: %d\n", score1);
    return true;
  }
  if(score1 == 2 || score1 == 3 || score1 == 12)
   {
     printf("You rolled: %d\n", score1);
     return false;
   }

  else
  {
    printf("You rolled %d\nYour point is %d\n", score1, score1);
  }

  for(;;){
    int score2 = roll_dice();
    if(score2 == 7) {
      printf("You rolled: %d\n", score2);
      return false; }
    if(score2 == score1) {
      printf("You rolled: %d\n", score2);
      return true; }
    else printf("You rolled: %d\n", score2);
    }
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Call `srand()` *once* in `main()`

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thank you!! I feel relieved, my book hasn't yet explained how ```srand()``` works (just says to use it for this problem) and asking this question made me realise I wasn't using it properly. Thank you, that solves everything!

Comment: The s in `srand` stands for seed. If you know this it makes more sense as to why you only want to call it once. You don’t want to manually re-seed your random number generator every time you generate a number.

Comment: @SafelyFast Ok that makes a lot more sense now! Thanks